# Kotlin multiplatform: How to start coroutine blockingly without runBlocking

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform

I use kotlin multiplatform which **prohibits using runBlocking in common code** since it is not supported by JS implementation.

My goal is to be able to call suspend functions from my non-suspend function like in the example below. Also I do not care about JS because I will use only JVM, Android, iOS targets

```
fun main() {
   runBlocking {
      doSomething()
   }
}

suspend fun doSomething() {
}
```

One solution I can think about is to create expected and actual classes and make runBlocking call separately on each platform actual class, but I want to avoid this as it will cause some code duplication.

```
 runBlocking {
      doSomething()
   }
```

Are there any better solution how to bridge blocking and non-blocking code together in common module?

Answer (score 2):

In the common code you can use:

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
}
```

or

```
MainScope().launch {
}
```

Depending on the scope you need.

And don't forget to use `-native-mt` version of coroutines if you're targeting iOS, more info [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mobile/concurrency-and-coroutines.html#multithreaded-coroutines)

This won't block you current thread, as `runBlocking` does, so if you really need this functionality, you indeed had to implement it with `expect`/`actual`, but I have not faced a similar need.